# Find out the depth of path in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, path

For any location gotten by the `Get-Location` cmdlet, if I have a path like this:

```
C:\Top\Middle\Bottom
```

I would say it's 3 levels deep.

If I have:

```
C:\
```

I would say it's the 0 level.
It could be 0 or 1 but the logic of depth is what matters.

Is there a way to figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way of doing this (assuming that your files do not have a `\` in their names) is like:

`$file.FullName.ToString().Split('\\').Count`

Comment: In my case it'd be `(Get-Location).Path.ToString().Split('\\').Count` right? It gives `2` for *both* `C:\ ` *and* `C:\Top`. For all deeper levels it works fine.

Comment: @laggingreflex I think thats correct. If you want you can special case drive letters only if you want (length will be three, and those are always drive letters)

Answer (score -1):

This code:

```
((Get-Location).Path.ToString().Split('\\') | ? {$_ -ne ""} ).Count
```

Returns 1 for c:\

Returns 2 for c:\users\

Comment: (Get-Location).Path.TrimEnd('\').split('\').count